# WPF: How to make a form's owner to be the calling app?

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF app is called by a C program (unmanaged). I want to make the WPF app stay on the screen where the calling app is. I have dual monitor.

So I want to make my WPF form WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" and set the owner to the calling app.

I can get the calling app via

```
Process.GetProcessById(CallingProcessID)
```

What is the next step to set WPF window Owner to the calling app?

Update:
The purpose of the question is to make WPF windows all stay on the screen where the calling program resides.

Comment: Does your unmanaged application display a window? Then you can set the `Onwer` property of your WPF window to the window handle of the unmanaged window.

Comment: Yes it does. Owner is of type Window and the unmanaged window handle is of type IntPtr. Any way to convert the handle to type Window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a window handle of your unmanaged application (HWND), you can use the [`WindowInteropHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper(v=vs.110).aspx) to set this HWND as your WPF window's parent.

```
WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(myWpfWindow);
wih.Owner = unmanagedOwnerHwnd;
```

The `Owner` property is of `IntPtr` type, so this should solve your issue.